# Hive: Is there a better way to percentile rank a column?

Tags: performance, hadoop, hive, rank, percentile

Currently, to percentile rank a column in hive, I am using something like the following.  I am trying to rank items in a column by what percentile they fall under, assigning a value form 0 to 1 to each item.  The code below assigns a value from 0 to 9, essentially saying that an item with a `char_percentile_rank` of 0 is in the bottom 10% of items, and a value of 9 is in the top 10% of items.  Is there a better way of doing this?

```
select item
    , characteristic
    , case when characteristic <= char_perc[0] then 0
        when characteristic <= char_perc[1] then 1
        when characteristic <= char_perc[2] then 2
        when characteristic <= char_perc[3] then 3
        when characteristic <= char_perc[4] then 4
        when characteristic <= char_perc[5] then 5
        when characteristic <= char_perc[6] then 6
        when characteristic <= char_perc[7] then 7
        when characteristic <= char_perc[8] then 8
        else 9
      end as char_percentile_rank
from (
    select split(item_id,'-')[0] as item
        , split(item_id,'-')[1] as characteristic
        , char_perc
    from (
        select collect_set(concat_ws('-',item,characteristic)) as item_set
            , PERCENTILE(BIGINT(characteristic),array(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9)) as char_perc
        from(
            select item
                , sum(characteristic) as characteristic
            from table
            group by item
        ) t1
    ) t2
    lateral view explode(item_set) explodetable as item_id
) t3
```

Note: I had to do the `collect_set` in order to avoid a self join, as the percentile function implicitly performs a `group by`.

I've gathered that the percentile function is horribly slow (at least in this usage).  Perhaps it would be better to manually calculate percentile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try removing one of your derived tables

```
select item
    , characteristic
    , case when characteristic <= char_perc[0] then 0
        when characteristic <= char_perc[1] then 1
        when characteristic <= char_perc[2] then 2
        when characteristic <= char_perc[3] then 3
        when characteristic <= char_perc[4] then 4
        when characteristic <= char_perc[5] then 5
        when characteristic <= char_perc[6] then 6
        when characteristic <= char_perc[7] then 7
        when characteristic <= char_perc[8] then 8
        else 9
      end as char_percentile_rank
from (
     select item, characteristic,
         , PERCENTILE(BIGINT(characteristic),array(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9)) over () as char_perc 
     from (
       select item
         , sum(characteristic) as characteristic             
       from table
       group by item            
     ) t1
) t2
```

Comment: The percentile function needs to have a group by - that's why I did the seemingly unnecessary collect_set(concat_ws(...)) - in order to make it one group.  If I instead group by item and characteristic, then it percentiles by item and characteristic, which I do not want.  Any ideas on how to avoid that?

Comment: I figured it out almost immediately after sleeping on it and coming back to it.  Just add over() on the percentile.  So the line should read: PERCENTILE(BIGINT(characteristic),array(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9)) over() as char_perc.  But it seems like both my original query and the new one have very similar performance.

Comment: @CharlieHaley is it possible to reference `PERCENTILE(BIGINT...)[i]` where `i = 0-8`? If so, you can move the case statement and remove 1 derived table

Comment: @CharlieHaley Another suggestion, is it possible to move `PERCENTILE(BIGINT(sum(characteristic),...) over () as characteristic` into the innermost query? Because I think window functions run after aggregation

Comment: I'll try it both ways and see if either produces a cleaner tree.

Comment: It looks like moving the percentile in either direction (inward or outward) does not affect the syntax tree, so it shouldn't affect performance either.  But it does make the query a bit better looking, so there's that.